# open xml has a bad performance with large data

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

Open xml write 20k row to excel file almost in 8 minutes using template which has 24 column. I have to improve this perfonmance so I must find the wrong things. Template file would cause poor perfonmace. But it hasn't any macro. Causing of poor performance would be a bug. But I haven't seen any bug about this. I need your help. How can I improve the performance using Open XMl or do you have any suggestion what is the best library to write large data to excel.

- OpenXml 2.5 .NetFramework 4.5

> worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save(); it takes 7 minutes.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
FileInfo temp_excel_file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(ConfigFile.ConfigsPaths["ExcelRaporFolder"], "temp", "Monitoring.xlsm"));
rapor_file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(ConfigFile.ConfigsPaths["ExcelRaporFolder"], "excel", FileName + ".xlsm"));
                            File.Copy(temp_excel_file.FullName, rapor_file.FullName);
                            Log.LogYaz(rapor_file.Name + "-Excell Açılıyor..");
SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(rapor_file.FullName, true);
                            IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = myDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>();
                            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)myDoc.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheets.Skip(1).First().Id);
                            SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().First();
foreach (var row_index in filtered_data)
{
 ...
 sheetData.AppendChild(Utils.CreateRow(row, 0, cell_data));
}
worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
myDoc.Close();
myDoc = null;
sw.Stop();
```

Comment: Code optimization questions should go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Open XML has a bug! Openxml uses a static memorystream when buffering capacity is exceeded. the bufferinbg capacity is 10 mb,I guess. So when you use openxml in multiple thread,occurs deadlock. Anymore I don't use open xml in multi thread.

Comment: I agree. Even if reading file, not writing, deadlock also happen!

Answer (score 1):

This might help to write large Excel file using Open XML files, while avoiding performance or Out of Memory exceptions.

Try using OpenXML Writer. its better than a simple foreach statement. Pls look [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/06/22/writing-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx)

```
          using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filename, true))
            {

                //For Diagonostice Only
                Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
                stopWatch.Start();

                WorkbookPart workbookPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart;
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
                string origninalSheetId = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart);

                WorksheetPart replacementPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                string replacementPartId = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(replacementPart);

                OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);
                OpenXmlWriter writer = OpenXmlWriter.Create(replacementPart);


                int rec = 0;
                #region Looping through data
                while (reader.Read())
                {

                    if (reader.ElementType == typeof(SheetData))
                    {
                        if (reader.IsEndElement)
                            continue;
                        writer.WriteStartElement(new SheetData());


                        for (int row = 0; row < listData.Count; row++)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(listData[row].WorkOrder))
                            {

                                Row newRow = new Row();
                                writer.WriteStartElement(newRow);

                                for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
                                {
                                    Cell newCell = new Cell();
                                    CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();

                                    //assigning value 

                                    cellValue.Text = row.ToString();
                                    //appending the value to cell

                                    newCell.Append(cellValue);

                                    writer.WriteElement(newCell);
                                }
                                writer.WriteEndElement();
                            }
                        }

                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (reader.IsStartElement)
                        {
                            writer.WriteStartElement(reader);
                        }
                        else if (reader.IsEndElement)
                        {
                            writer.WriteEndElement();
                        }
                    }
                }
                #endregion

                reader.Close();
                writer.Close();

                //replace the templateSheet with DataSheet.                  
                Sheet sheet = workbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>()
                       .Where(s => s.Id.Value.Equals(origninalSheetId)).First();

                sheet.Id.Value = replacementPartId;
                workbookPart.DeletePart(worksheetPart);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to load the file content and write it in a Memory Stream,
seek to the beginning and open the document with this memory stream.
After the save Operation you can write the content of the memory stream back to a file.

I am not sure if it will help you, but i am using this sequence myself with open Word.

Answer (score -2):

Check the time taken in the foreach loop and Utils.CreateRow(row, 0, cell_data) function. Based on this optimize your code using Linq.

Thanks!